# Why is #attached library load not working, but drupal_add_library works?

Tags: 7, javascript

This question is specific to D7:
I'm trying to load in jQuery UI modal into the theme. I've put the following in my `THEMENAME_preprocess_html`:

```
$variables['page']['content']['#attached']['library'][] = array('system', 'ui.dialog');
```

This isn't loading the library at all.

DPM-ing the `$variables` array after the above line shows that it's all added correctly (There's even other stuff in there like, addthis.js):
[image: DPM of variables array]

Direct link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iC3h.png

Obviously all caches were cleared. At this point the console shows an error that `dialog is not defined`. But as soon as I add this (in the same function, just below the `#attached` line):

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');
```

then the dialog modal opens and starts playing nicely. Am I doing something wrong with #attached? I'm really puzzled as to why one's working and the other doesn't. Ideally I'd like to use `#attached` in the cases where the variables array gets cached and the preprocess doesn't get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the render array has already been rendered before the preprocess functions, '#attached' is not supported in preprocess functions until Drupal 8.

The issue where it was added is https://www.drupal.org/node/2346369

The related Drupal 8 change record is https://www.drupal.org/node/2352319 - this also shows the supported way of doing it in Drupal 7.

Using drupal_add_library() will work, but it will not be cached, so you will take a performance hit. You are better off adding it to the #attached array at a different step in the process.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, so I guess the only way to go is to use `drupal_add_library`. Will this have issues when caching is turned on?

Comment: I know the use of drupal_add_css & drupal_add_js are affected by caching but I think maybe it depends where you are using it (using it in blocks for example doesn't work properly when cached). I haven't looked into it enough to understand entirely but you will find out with a test run. Also, you could move your code, unless it really has to be in preprocess html. It could maybe go in hook_page_build() or hook_page_alter() instead.

Comment: yeah I don't know why I stuck with preprocess. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: "For whatever reason (maybe just oversight), '#attached' is not supported in preprocess functions until Drupal 8." <---- This is because the render array has already been rendered before the preprocess functions. Using drupal_add_library() will work, but it will not be cached, so you will take a performance hit. You  are better off adding it to the #attached array at a different step in the process.